# What does "Quick" mean?

Tags: algorithms, algorithm-analysis

> What does quick/fast mean in the context of computer science?

I couldn't find a definition online (poor google fu), and I want to provide a referenced/cited definition for fast for an article I'm writing.

Answer (score 8):

It's a completely informal term. It has no fixed definition.  Just as "He was driving quickly" doesn't define any exact range of speeds.

And, just like the driving example, what would be considered "quick" depends on context.  If you gave me a $\Theta(n^3)$ algorithm for graph isomorphism, I'd bite your hand off; if you gave me a $\Theta(n^3)$ algorithm for sorting, I'd think you were an idiot.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes "a fast algorithm" means "a polynomial-time algorithm". But this is always informal, and depends on the context.